# apple store showing different page in wget

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, security, python, wget

istore.apple.com live url is different that url which is downloaded using wget

Open this url in browser

```
https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios-games-action/id7001?mt=8&letter=A
```

You will see pagination pages like 1,2,3 etc(A will be selected).

but when i download the page using wget

```
wget https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios-games-action/id7001?mt=8&letter=A
```

After downloading in your system open the file you will see different page(You will not see A Selected and pagination pages will not be there).

Why this happens and how to get original page??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `$ wget 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios-games-action/id7001?mt=8&letter=A'`

And got this ==>
[image]

So I cannot reproduce the issue you are mentioning here.
I would suggest you to compare the source code of the wget downloaded webpage (offline) and the source code of the original page to find why the result is not the same.

Please bear in mind that connecting to a web server through HTTPS involve many operations. The WebServer might returns different information based on your User-Agent, screen resolution, session cookies...

Comment: To complete my answer, You can check the source of the webpage, copy and paste it in a file. then some tools such as vimdiff are great to highlight what lines are different between the two files (available on OS X and Linux) $ vimdiff wgetfile.htm orginal.html